# Simple animation play/reverse button

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Trying to play animation toggling between play and reverse play with animate.js framework.

HTML

```
<button class="btn">PLAY</button>
<div class="square"></div>
```

JS

```
/** animation */
let animeSquare = anime({
  targets: '.square',
  translateX: '100px',
  duration: 500,
  autoplay: false,
});


/** button */
$('.btn').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('is-active')) {
    animeSquare.reverse();
    $(this).removeClass('is-active');
  } else {
    animeSquare.play();
    $(this).addClass('is-active');
  }
});
```

The problem is that I must to hit the button twice to play animation. Why?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/aitormendez/pen/ymyzoq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anime plugin has:

- [direction property](https://animejs.com/documentation/#direction)
- [begin / complete callbacks](https://animejs.com/documentation/#beginComplete)

Moreover, because you don't have a loop you need to restart every time.

Hence, your code can be reduced to:

```js
let animeSquare = anime({
    targets: '.square',

    direction: 'normal',  // normal or reverse????

    /** Properties to animate */
    translateX: '100px',

    /** Animation settings */
    duration: 500,
    autoplay: false,

    begin: function (anim) {

    },
    complete: function (anim) {
        // change direction..... so the next time you play....
        anim.direction = (anim.direction == 'normal') ? 'reverse' : 'normal';
    }
});

$('.btn').click(function () {
    animeSquare.restart();
});
```

```css
.square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>


<button class="btn">PLAY</button>
<div class="square"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code which i tried is

```
let animeSquare = anime({
  targets: '.square',

  /** Properties to animate */
  translateX: '100px',

  /** Animation settings */
  duration: 500,
  autoplay: false,
});

$('.btn').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('is-active')) {
    animeSquare.direction = "reverse"
    animeSquare.play();
    $(this).removeClass('is-active');
  } else {
    animeSquare.direction = "normal"
    animeSquare.play();
    $(this).addClass('is-active');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the following logic

When playing for the first time you use `animeSquare.play();` but from the second count onwards you need to reverse the animation using `animeSquare.reverse();` and then play the animation after reversing using `animeSquare.play();`.

```js
let animeSquare = anime({
  targets: '.square',

  /** Properties to animate */
  translateX: '100px',

  /** Animation settings */
  duration: 500,
  autoplay: false,
});
var c=0;
$('.btn').click(function() {
  if(c==0){
    animeSquare.play();
    c++;
  }else{
    
    animeSquare.reverse();
    animeSquare.play();
    
  }
  
  console.log(animeSquare);
});
```

```css
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">PLAY</button>
<div class="square"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>
```